# Open folder when a user clicks on a button of dialog box and prevent the dialog from closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have custom dialog box with a button and a link_label which i use as a button.

When the user clicks the label i want to open a certain folder at window explorer and keep the dialog open. I know which button the user clicks by determining what Dialog result to return.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;      
}

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;     
}
```

At another class i have a method which returns a bool value according to the dialogResult:

```
DialogResult res = dig.ShowDialog();
return res == DialogResult.No;
```

Then if this methods return true i need to open the win explorer and keep the dialog open until the button is clicked.
the problem is when im tring to prevent the dialog to closing with `FormClosing` event of MyDialog form, the explorer is not opened. And if i am not using `FormClosing` the explorer opens but the dialog is closed.

```
private void MyDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I cant use the Linkclicked event of the form because i want this dialog to be reusable and handle the result each time. (open different paths depends on where i use the dialog)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why explorer is not opened is that when you reject the form close, the parent code doesnt continue to open explorer,
What you want to achieve is a bit unclear to me, but the way you do it is not possible, as a suggestion why not open the `FolderBrowserDialog` from inisde `MyDialog` based on `label` click and closing `MyDialog` on `button` click, rather than having the parent handle the decision.

Comment: What I need is to handle the link click without closing the dialog and without implementing what I want on the link onClick event. In other words just to know the user clicked on the link without closing the dialog

Comment: The reason i cant use FolderBrowserDialog  at the label_onClick method is because i want to open specific path depends on which class the dialog is called from

Comment: @ATT, Why not pass that specific path to your `MyDialog` class from parent and open it from inside?